# Updating JDK version to match JRE?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, java-7

Version 60 of the Java JRE 7 has just been released and I have updated it.

I understand that Java 8 is not supported yet.

However, what should I do about the JDK? Should I also update to v60 (now at v45)?

Is there an android page somewhere providing this information? Couldn't find it, but I'm somewhat slow.

Thank you, guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have 51th update of both JDK and JRE7  ,  both are running fine  , Don't go for latest ones so early because there may be some frustrating problems that may come while using. wait for responses then give it a go.

Comment: Smart but, where to check for these problems?

Comment: Problems can't be countered so early , people start using it even their own team do Q.A on it  , then if people face problems then they will post it to Java Support then they will come up with new version.

Comment: @Lara please mark it as answer , if i cleared ur doubts.

Comment: Sure. There you go. To be honest, though, I was left wondering which is then the best version of the JDK to work with.

Comment: @Lara buddy i will suggest u to look at this website. http://javatester.org/version.html 
may be u will get a satisfying answer.well ,  i will stick with jdk7_u_51 for a while more, b/c it suits my needs up-till now , when i will go dynamic with my apps then i will switch to some new update. Thanks for ur co operation bro.

Comment: Appreciate it, my friend.